# SQL UPDATE Using Datepickr.js Resetting Date to 0000-00-00

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I have the datepickr.min.js running on my website and it's working when I do an insert into the database but when I am doing an UPDATE it's inserting the dateformat as 0000-00-00 which I find extrememly strange as it's using the same code and ID.  Here's the javascript:

```
new datepickr('datepick', {
            'dateFormat': 'Y-m-d'
        })
```

Here's the form element:

```
<input size='11' id='datepick' name='editfrom' value='$editDate' style='padding:2px;'/>
```

$editDate is pulling in the original date that was correctly inserted.  Here's the update:

```
UPDATE b_report_week SET COMMENCE='".$POST['editfrom']."' WHERE ID='".$_POST['ID']."'";
```

This is just a snippet of the code, there are other fields being updated and they update fine so it is correctly finding the correct row.  The field in the database is set to DATE which I know takes 2013-12-06 format.

Why is it setting the date format back from 2013-12-06 that was inserted into the database correctly using datepickr but not updating it correctly and resetting back to 0000-00-00.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally sorted it.  Anybody wanting to perform an UPDATE.  On the processing page use:

```
UPDATE b_report_week SET COMMENCE='".date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['editfrom']))."'
```

This ensured the correct format was inserted into the database.